# How can I hook and edit on the fly an image uploaded

Tags: images, uploads

I'm new in wordpress plugin development and I'm trying to hook my function to one of wordpress's upload / attachements functions.

My target is to:
- hook to wordpress function (I've tried: wp_handle_upload, wp_handle_upload_prefilter)
- use image/media resource in my function (apply filter on image)
- return modified resource to further processing by wordpress core.

Is there a way to achieve that?

The code I'm using is similar to:

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload', 'handle_upload');

function handle_upload($resource){

   $tools->tool_blurImage($resource);

return $resource;

}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_handle_upload/ The filter applies after the file is uploaded.  In the args you get the filename and path so you can do whatever you want to the file.

Comment: Indeed, I did apply the filter after the image was uploaded. Thanks!